# Example for non-virtual multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Is there a real-world example where non-virtual multiple inheritance is being used? I'd like to have one mostly for didactic reasons. Slapping around classes named `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, where `B` and `C` inherit from `A` and `D` inherits from `B` and `C` is perfectly fine for explaining the question "Does/Should a `D` object have one or two `A` sub-objects?", but bears no weight about why we even have both options. Many examples care about why we do want virtual inheritance, but why would we not want virtual inheritance?

I know what virtual base classes are and how to express that stuff in code. I know about diamond inheritance and examples of multiple inheritance with a virtual base class are abundant.

The best I could find is vehicles. The base class is `Vehicle` which is inherited by `Car` and `Boat`. Among other things, a `Vehicle` has `occupants()` and a `max_speed()`. So an `Amphibian` that inherits from both `Car` and `Boat` inherits different `max_speed()` on land and water – and that makes sense –, but also different `occupants()` – and that does not make sense. So the `Vehicle` sub-objects aren't really independent; that is another problem which might be interesting to solve, but this is *not* the question.

Is there an example, that makes sense as a real-world model, where the two sub-objects are really independent?

Comment: This may be more real-world than what you have in mind, but SFML uses non-virtual multiple inheritance fairly often. Examples: [`sf::Window`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php), [`sf::Sprite`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php), [`sf::VertexBuffer`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1VertexBuffer.php), and [`sf::Shape`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shape.php), to name a few.

Comment: An implementation of tuple that inherits from leafs may inherit multiple times from the same type to take advantage of EBO if the same type appears more than one time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking like an OOP programmer, trying to design abstract models of things. C++ multiple inheritance, like many things in C++, is a *tool* that has a particular effect. Whether it maps onto some OOP model is irrelevant next to the utility of the tool itself. To put it another way, you don't need a "real-world model" to justify non-virtual inheritance; you just need a real-world *use case*.

Because a derived class inherits the members of a base class, inheritance often is used in C++ as a means of collecting a set of common functionality together, sometimes with minimal interaction from the derived class, and injecting this functionality directly into the derived class.

The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern and other mixin-like constructs are mechanisms for doing this. The idea is that you have a base class that is a template, and its template parameter is the *derived* class that uses it. This allows the base class to have some access to the derived class itself without `virtual` functions.

The simplest example I can think of in C++ is `enable_shared_from_this`, which allows an object whose lifetime is currently managed by a `shared_ptr` to actually retrieve a `shared_ptr` to that object just from a pointer/reference to that object. That uses CRTP to add the various members and interfaces needed to make `shared_from_this` possible to the derived class. And since the inheritance is public, it also allows `shared_ptr`'s various functions that "enable shared_from_this" to to detect that a particular type has the `shared_from_this` stuff in it and to properly initialize it.

`enable_shared_from_this` doesn't need virtual inheritance, and indeed would probably not work very well with it.

Now imagine that I have some other CRTP class that injects some other functionality into an object. This functionality has nothing to do with `shared_ptr`, but it uses CRTP and inheritance.

Well, if I now write some type that wants to inherit from both `enable_shared_from_this` *and* this other functionality, well, that works just fine. There is no need for virtual inheritance, and in fact doing so would only make composition that much harder.

Virtual inheritance is not free. It fundamentally changes a bunch of things about how a type relates to its base classes. If you inherit from such a type, your constructors have to initialize any virtual base classes *directly*. The layout of such a type is very odd and is highly unlikely to be standardized. And various other things. C++ tries not to make programmers pay for functionality they don't use, so if you don't need the special properties of virtual inheritance, you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 1):

Its the same reason C++ has non-virtual methods -- because the implementation is simpler and more efficient if you use non-virtual inheritance, so you need to explicitly ask for virtual inheritance if you want it.  Since you *don't* need it if your classes never use multiple inheritance, that is the default.